# TeX Live can't find "tcfmgr.map" and "fmtutil.cnf"

Tags: installing, texlive

I ran into some problems with TeX and re-installed TeX Live.
(I'm using Fedora 16 x86_64)

Now, when I try to run `pdflatex`, it says:

```
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found.

fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found
```

I did `texhash`, `texconfig rehash` and I still have the same problem.

Actually, the two files tex complains that it can't find are in:

```
/usr/share/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr.map

/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
```

I've no idea what I should do next.

Comment: What's the result of `kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf`?

Comment: Hashing/rehashing helped in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Martin.

It turned out that I've installed different versions of texlive, one from my yum repository, one from online texlive resource, which seemed to cause some conflicts.

When I first tried to fix the problem, I did "yum remove texlive", without realizing this is not enough -- I ended up removing all the package "yum search texlive" has listed and re-installed texlive from yum repository and it works now.